# Scrapy xml output <![CDATA[<html lang="en"

Tags: python, xml, scrapy

In my scrapy script I am crawling webpage source and save the output in xml format. In that xml output the content is starting with

```
"<!DOCTYPE html> <!--[if IE 7]><html lang="en" "
```

but what I need in the output xml is

```
" <![CDATA[<html lang="en" "
```

How can I get that in my scrapy script?

my code is given below..

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector    
from Dell.items import DellItem
from scrapy.http.request import Request
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.sgml import SgmlLinkExtractor    
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CSVFeedSpider


class DellSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "dell"
    allowed_domains = ["dell.com"]
    start_urls = (

               'http://jobs.dell.com/united-states-jobs/',

    )
    def parse(self, response):
                item = response.meta['item']
                response = requests.get(response.url)
                html =response.content
                item['source']=str(html)
                return item
```

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking. Can you provide the code you have so far, and the link to the page in question?

Comment: I have edited my question. Please look into it.

Comment: Your question is still not complete. What are you trying to accomplish? Why do you think your data needs to be in CDATA? Why do you think your item will be in the `response.meta['item']`? Did you put it there? If yes, where is this code? Why are you using `requests` when `scrapy` already has all the means to get the page body (`response.body`)?